# Finding hard drives on fresh Ubuntu 18.04 install

Tags: 18.04, hard-drive, ntfs

I have 2 hard drives not listed by Ubuntu 18.04.
Gparted finds them as `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`.
They are both formatted as NTFS drives.
Ubuntu finds `/dev/sde`, which is an external NTFS drive.

How is this solved?

Comment: Home > Other locations ( on LHS panel) . Can you see them now ?

Answer (score 0):

External USB drives are automatically mounted in /media. In order to mount internal drives automatically, you need to follow the instructions at https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-auto-mounting-windows-ntfs-file-system/

Hope this helps,
Larry